# getting error to import a module in python

Tags: python, python-import

pip install google-auth

```
try: 
    from  google.auth.transport import requests as GoogleRequest
    print('Google Request include')
except:
    print('Google Request NOT include')

try: 
    from google.oauth2 import id_token as GoogleToken
    print('Google Token include')
except:
    print('Google Token NOT include')
```

Python:2.7 I have install and import a module in file but geting this output

Module Link
https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.html

```
Google Request NOT include
Google Token include
Google Request NOT include
Google Request include
Google Token include
Google Token include
```

why? Please help me